# Tooltip on the right side of the input

Tags: html, css

I coded this simple CSS-trick to show when you click on the input (:focus) a tooltip will give you some information about the input. Everything is working but, the tooltip it's displayed below the input and not over. Actually I know that I can use margin to fix it, but I'm asking if there's a "more" clean way that when you use position absolute in this way, it will automatically align the tooltip over the input.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
    <span class="input_info">Info1</span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="input_info">Info2</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input_info {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus + .input_info {
    display: block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xzqsaobu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it with `position: absolute` and `relative`.

- On the container, set `position: relative`, and `display: table` (shrink to fit).
- For the `position: absolute` tooltip, set `top: 0`, and `left: 100%` (moves to the right edge of the relative container).

You can also horizonally center the fields in a page with this approach.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11anb6az/)**

```css
.fieldset {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  /* margin: auto; */
}
.input_info {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
}
input[type="text"]:focus + .input_info {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldset">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
  <span class="input_info">Info1</span>
</div>
<div class="fieldset">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
  <span class="input_info">Info2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to change `display: block` to `display: inline-block`, remove the `margin-left` and `position: absolute;`.

**[Your fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/xzqsaobu/1/)**.

Snippet:

```css
.input_info {
  background: #000;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  display: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus + .input_info {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username">
<span class="input_info">Info1</span>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Password">
<span class="input_info">Info2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what if there will be and additional inline-block element after one of these inputs?

Comment: @SLy_huh Then use `~`  sibling combinator instead of `+` :) https://jsfiddle.net/xzqsaobu/3/

Comment: and now try to add info `span` for the second input in the first div. Get me right, wasnt going to fail your answer, but wanted to improve it, to let the author get the best solution `=)`

Comment: @SLy_huh Then use `+` in case you want to display one by one, or `~` if you want to display two at the same time :p https://jsfiddle.net/xzqsaobu/4/